# Validator.TryValidateProperty Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, validation, data-annotations

I am trying to implement Validator.TryValidateProperty and even though there is a [Required] DataAnnotation, the TryValidateProperty returns a valid response.

Here is my Customer partial class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Customer.Metadata))]
public partial class Customer : global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject 
{
   ...
private sealed class Metadata
    {

        [Required]
        [SSNValidAttribute(ErrorMessage = "The SSN should be 9 numeric characters without any punctuation.")]
        [DisplayName("SSN")]
        public String SSN { get; set; }
...
```

And here is the code that is returning True:

```
...
var customer = new Customer();
            customer.SSN = "";
            var vc = new ValidationContext(customer, null, null);
            vc.MemberName = "SSN";
            var res = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(customer.SSN, vc, res);
...
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `SSNValidAttribute`?

Comment: @mellamokb, I got the same behavior even without that attribute, when I tried the code.

Comment: You should accept the answer that solved your issue OR add notes why it did not. (probably does since it was YOUR answer here)

Answer (score 14):

Ok, just found the solution for dealing with the sealed `MetadataType` class.

```
var customer = new Customer();
TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent
(new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider
    (customer.GetType()), customer.GetType());
customer.SSN = "";
var vc = new ValidationContext(customer, null, null);
vc.MemberName = "SSN";
var res = new List<ValidationResult>();
var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(customer.SSN, vc, res);
```

I had to add the following:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent
(new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider
    (customer.GetType()), customer.GetType());
```

Found solution at this address:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/149264/333396.aspx

Comment: Had a similar issue with WPF ignoring completely validation metadata when using a MetadataType buddy class. Since I was using POCOs with EF, I modified the TT generator to add the above line in the static constructor.